# Set of two cycles generate $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do I show that $S_n$ is generated by the set $\{(1\space i), i=2,3,...,n\}$?

Is it correct to say that since each product of elements of $\{(1\space i), i=2,3,...,n\}$ is an element of $S_n$, we know that $\{(1\space i), i=2,3,...,n\}\subset S_n$, and how can I prove that $S_n\subset\{(1\space i), i=2,3,...,n\}$?

Comment: @user149418 The set of generators in the alleged dupe is different.

Comment: it's not a duplicate

Comment: @AlexR thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion $\subset$ is correctly justified. The other way ($\supset$) can be proved by giving an explicit construction of
$$S_n \ni \pi = (1\ i_1)(1\ i_2)\ldots(1\ i_k)$$
Where $k$ is finite, $\pi$ is a given permutation and the $i_j$ can be chosen. For this, look at products $(1\ i_k)\ldots(1\ i_1)(1\ i_k)$. What are they?

For example $(1\ 2)(1\ 3)(1\ 2) = \;?$

Observe the following:

> $$(1\ i_k)\ldots(1\ i_1)(1\ i_k) = (i_1\ i_2\ \ldots\ i_k)$$
>  So we can generate any cycle with this construction. Since every permutation is a product of disjoint cycles, we can decompose a permutation into its cycles and apply the construction on each cycle. The product of these is a representation of $\pi$ as a product of the swaps $(1\ i)$ for some $i$.
>  For example $\pi = (1 3 2)(4 5) = (12)(13)\cdot (1 5)(1 4)(1 5) = (12)(13)(15)(14)(15)$

Comment: are they a permutation $(1,i_1,i_2,...,i_k)$?

Comment: @Stan_Allen Almost. They form a cycle, but wich cycle?

Comment: $(12)(13)(12)=(23)$

Comment: @Stan_Allen Correct. Do you notice what happens for the general case? Do you see how we can now write an arbitrary permutation?

Comment: not exactly....

Comment: Okay see what $(1\ 2)(1\ 3)(1\ 4)(1\ 2)$ gives you. Note that every permutation can be written as the product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: $(12)(13)(14)(12)=(243)$

Comment: does this mean that the answer to your general example is $(i_1, i_k,i_{k-1},...,i_2)$?

Comment: @Stan_Allen Yes! I decided to re-index so $$(i_1\ \ldots\ i_k) = (1\ i_k)(1\ i_{k-1})\ldots(1\ i_1)(1\ i_k)$$

Comment: I get it now! thanks a lot for all the help! :)